# Forcing CsvHelper to use a period decimal separator when generating CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I have a C# / .Net 4.8 WPF app. I'm using CsvHelper to generate CSV files for various lists. I have the following code:

```
public void WriteRecord(List<T> data, string filename)
{
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(data);
            writer.Flush();
        }
   }
}
```

I'm using a T generic because that way I can save any type of list to a CSV file. It's working fine, except for one problem. If the list type has a DateTime field, and the values include milliseconds, it is using a comma decimal separator between the seconds and milliseconds. This is a problem as I am using comma for the field separators. So in other words, if the object being saved has a DateTime field such as **"2020/02/17 11:45:32.153"** it is saving it as **"2020/02/17 11:45:32,153"**

Is there a way to force it to use a period decimal separator instead of a comma?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/697 Define your own format.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you! Will post what I did below:

Answer (score 0):

Following the link that "Louis Go" posted in his comment above, this is what I did:

```
public void WriteRecord(List<T> data, string filename)
{
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<DateTime>().Formats = new[] { "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff" };
            csv.WriteRecords(data);
            writer.Flush();
        }
   }
}
```

It's working perfectly now - using a period for the decimal separator, instead of a comma. Thanks Louis Go!